# Adobe Fireworks CS5 only allows me to select a restricted range of colors

Tags: adobe-fireworks

I'm having problems selecting colors in Adobe Fireworks CS5 because when I select a color (either through the color swatches, the color mixer or the windows color picker) it will snap to one of those which are already present in the swatches window. So say I select color #2a2a2a, Fireworks will transform it into #333333 and I'll only be allowed to use that one.

Is there a way to stop this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure "Snap to web safe" is turned off in the context menu of the color picker.

[A Screenshot of the menu option](http://cl.ly/3A2N3o0b443J2l3a3n2D)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might be using 8-bit (256-color) mode.  Have you tried changing the bit depth of your project, or changing the available colors?  (See [this Adobe knowledgebase article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Fireworks/10.0_Using/WS4c25cfbb1410b0021e63e3d1152b00d6af-7ff0.html) on the latter.)

Comment: How do I change the bit depth of my project? I've found no useful information on the guide.

Comment: Hmm I can't find how to change it directly via Google, I'll check when I'm at home.  But changing your export settings might help? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/fireworks/cs/using/WS4c25cfbb1410b0021e63e3d1152b00d6af-7ff6.html

Comment: My color mixer looks like this: http://gabrielecirulli.com/p/20110517-204043.png and that doesn't seem right at all.

Comment: Those look like web-safe colors.

Comment: Does anyone know any more than that?